# Consultar todos los registros relación muchos a muchos en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo mis modelos `frecuencia` y `horarios`

```
class Frecuencia extends Model

{

    public function horarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Horario::class, 'rutas');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Horario extends Model
{
    public function frecuencias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Frecuencia::class, 'rutas');
    }
}
```

Mi tabla pivote se llama ruta e intento obtener todos los horarios de las frecuencias mi modelo

```
public function prueba()
{

   $rutas = Frecuencia::all();

   dd($rutas->horarios);

   return view ('Web.index', compact('rutas'));
}
```

Error presentado

> "Property [horarios] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Hazle el dd($rutas) y ya verás que el attr se llama horario no horarios, de todos modos cuando veas el dd de rutas lo verás más claro.

Comment: @EduBw lee bien la pregunta, lo que dices es totalmente incorrecto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal sería que cargues las relaciones antes de mostrarlas, para evitar un problema conocido llamado "N+1", y posteriormente sí trabajes/muestres los horarios que deseas, eso lo logras con el método with() al momento de hacer la consulta, y el parámetro que le pasas es el nombre de la relación, posteriormente iteras sobre el resultado para ver los horarios correspondientes a cada ruta:

```
public function prueba()
{

   $rutas = Frecuencia::with('horarios')->get();

   foreach ($rutas as $ruta) {
       dump($ruta->horarios);
   }

   return view ('Web.index', compact('rutas'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Al hacer $rutas = Frecuencia::all(); te traes todas las rutas para acceder a cada ruta debes hacer un foreach y ya funcionara el dd para ver los horarios de cada ruta.

```
public function prueba()
{

   $rutas = Frecuencia::all();

   foreach ($rutas as $ruta) {
       dd($ruta->horarios);
   }

   return view ('Web.index', compact('rutas'));
}
```